# Characterize entire functions satisfying $|f(z)|=(x^2+y^2)e^x$

Tags: complex-analysis

Clearly, $f(z)=z^2e^z$ is one such function. Suppose $g$ is another entire function satisfying the given criterion, then $|f/g|=1$ when $z\neq0$. I want to invoke Liouville's theorem and conclude all such functions are given by $f(z)e^{i\theta}$ for any fixed real number $\theta$. Since $f$ and $g$ are entire and nonzero when $z\neq0$, the ratio $f/g$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

I think I'm on the right track but unsure how to make the above argument precise at $z=0$.

Comment: Have you seen [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem)?

Comment: (Liouville, not Louisville.)

Comment: I used to be good at spelling, I swear! I don't think I have seen Riemann's theorem before. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a standard theorem that sends that if $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, $z_0\in D$, $f$ is holomorphic on $D\backslash \{ z_0\}$ and bounded on some neighborhood containing $z_0$, then this singularity is removable in the sense that there exist a unique complex number $f(z_0)$ such that the function
$$
\widetilde{f}(z)=\begin{cases}f(z_0) & \text{if }z=z_0 \\ f(z) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
defined on $D$ is holomorphic.

This theorem applies here so that $f/g$ has an entire extension.  This extension is bounded, hence a constant, hence $f/g$ is constant.

Keep in mind you are using the fact that the only possible location that $g$ could have a root is $z=0$, so that $f/g$ is automatically analytic everywhere except the origin.

EDIT:  Ahh yes, so evidently, this "standard theorem" has a name.  See  Dylan Moreland's comment :)